# How does your Application class know when the app has finished?

Tags: java, android

I've got a database singleton and I want to call .close() on it when the app finishes.

I can call .open() on the database in onCreate() in the Application class, but where do I call .close()?

Comment: Let me guess: onTerminate() looks promising.

Comment: A quote from the Android docs: `This method is for use in emulated process environments. It will never be called on a production Android device, where processes are removed by simply killing them; no user code (including this callback) is executed when doing so.` Hence it wouldn't work on an actual device :/

Comment: OK, my second guess is to register an activity callback: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html

Comment: This would only work on API levels 7+ though wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html#onActivityStopped(android.app.Activity) would be appropriate, I think.

Comment: Isn't that just activity specific, rather than application specific though? I want to know when my application is being killed...

Comment: Maybe I could have a root activity, and open the database in that, and close the database when onFinish is called in that activity.

Comment: if application is killed, then even process is killed, so I dont think you can get any callbacks. You should think of moving the code to activity , since application usually stays a lot longer and your database connection might waste memory

Comment: Okay then, would having a root activity manage the opening and closing of the database work then?

Comment: Yeah what I do is sort of look for foreground activity. After each foreground activity dies, I can decrement. Once I reach zero and stay there for a reasonable amount of time, I know I am safe to close such resources. Ended up making virtual lifecycle callbacks in my app this way. So this way works no matter how many tasks you have or where things start from. IF you can only run and start your app from one place and everything goes only in a single linear fashion, then yes teh root activity approach works too.

Comment: If you answer the question with that I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah what I do is sort of look for foreground activity. After each foreground activity dies, I can decrement. Once I reach zero and stay there for a reasonable amount of time, I know I am safe to close such resources. Ended up making virtual lifecycle callbacks in my app this way. So this way works no matter how many tasks you have or where things start from. IF you can only run and start your app from one place and everything goes only in a single linear fashion, then yes the root activity approach works too.

Specifically like this:

**BaseActivity**

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {

   public void onResume() {
      MyBaseApplicationType app = (MyBaseApplicationType)getApplicationContext();
      app.incrementForegroundActivity();
   }

   public void onPause() {
      MyBaseApplicationType app = (MyBaseApplicationType)getApplicationContext();
      app.decrementForegroundActivity();
   }

}
```

**MyBaseApplication**

```
public class MyBaseApplication extends Application {

   private int mForegroundActivities;
   private Handler mHandler;

   public void onCreate() {
      mHandler = new Handler();
   }

   public void decrementForegroundActivity() {
      mForegroundActivities--;
      if (mForegroundActivities == 0) {
         mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 1000 /*about a second*/);
      }
   }

   public void incrementForegroundActivities() {
      mForegroundActivities++;
   }

   private Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
         if (mForegroundActivities == 0) {
            // Listeners of this broadcast can then clean up anything
            // as needed.
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.my.package.ACTION_BACKGROUNDED");
            sendBroadcast(intent);
         }
      }
   };

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally you should close database connections in `onDestroy()` or `onStop()`. `onDestroy()` is called just before the activity is removed from memory and destroyed. `onStop()` is called when you go to a different application. Either one works, but `onDestroy()` is generally better because `onStop()` slows down app switching.

More info: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html